# iOS Universal Link active in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ios-universal-links

I am studying universal links related to work.

The scenarios that need to be implemented are:

- web page login
- check server login information
- run app when server universal link is called

I tested it with a virtual nodejs server and I don't get it.

- Universal link works fine
  main.html
  client button click

```
<button id="tigrisButton" type="button" class="navyBtn"onClick="location.href='https://test40.com/testios'">tigris</button>
```

- Universal link works not fine
  main.js
  document load js excute

```
function goTigirs() {
    var button = document.getElementById("tigrisButton");

    var event = new MouseEvent("click", {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
    });
    button.dispatchEvent(event); 
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", goTigirs);
```

Do I really need an actual event on the client for universal to work?

I would really appreciate your feedback